# Randomly sample rows (first dimension) of an array with unknown dimension

Tags: python, numpy

When the dimension is known, the task is trivial. Take a 2D array:

```
a = np.random.randint(10, a=(5,2))
a[np.random.choice(a.shape[0]), :]
```

However, in my function, the dimension of the array is arbitrary. How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the size of the 1st dimension to determine the random range:

```
a[np.random.randint(0,a.shape[0],10)]
```

or if you prefer, include an Ellipsis

```
a[np.random.randint(0,a.shape[0],10),...]
```

1 indexing array selects from rows by default.